# Ticker text not not shown in status bar upon receiving a push message

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I integrated Parse.com Push into my Android app (using the Parse SDK 1.7.0 for Android). I followed the instructions in the Quickstart on Parse.com: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing.

First my app crashed upon receiving a push notification. Logcat indicated a nullpointexception error associated with the notification icon. The Parse documentation (https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android) indicates that by default, the application's launcher icon is used for a notification. This somehow did not work. This crash was fixed after adding the following tag to the AndroidManifest, to customize the notification icon: `<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>`.

Notifications are now received succesfully, but no ticker text is shown in the status bar of the Android device. The screenshots on the Parse.com website, which show a preview of the push notification to be sent, do show this ticker tekst, so it is supposed to be shown. Upon receiving the push message, the text of the notification that is shown in the notification tray should also be shown in the status bar for a few seconds, when the notification icon appears. In my case, only the notification icon appears. The notification text is only visible in the notification tray.

Am I the only one experiencing this behaviour? Is this perhaps a bug in the recently released Parse SDK 1.7.0 for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse Android SDK 1.8.1 was released recently. You can extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and override

```
 protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent)
 protected int getSmallIconId(Context context, Intent intent)
```

in order to add a ticker to the notification. Lastly don't forget to list the Custom Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml and add the intent actions required by Parse. Check the link for more information.

https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android